# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunListener

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

I encounter this error when i run espresso test, the full log is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunListener;
                                                     at android.support.test.internal.runner.RunnerArgs$Builder.fromBundle(RunnerArgs.java:150)
                                                     at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.parseRunnerArgs(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:224)
                                                     at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onCreate(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:199)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4698)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/ro.adr.test.test-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/ro.adr.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ro.adr.test.test-1/lib/x86, /data/app/ro.adr.test-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I'm sure in build.gradle and library project build.gradle has no junit conflict, here is my app/build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
    compile project(":adr")
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    String ver = "23.4.0"

    compile "com.android.support:design:${ver}"

    compile files("${System.env.HOME}/Dropbox/jvs/ro2/build/libs/ro2.jar")

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2')
    compile 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:0.10'
}
```

Comment: Where are your test dependencies? ` testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, I check above log output "/data/app/ro.adr.test.test-1/base.apk", and decompile it with `apktool`, in normal case, it should include

```
base/smali/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.smali
```

but it does't, so i think the best way is:

- rm all build dirs in android project
- rm /data/app/all-project-relative-dir
- rerun debug
- above steps can do it with script

**update**

above solution is not perfect, if you use gradle, you can:

```
gradle --daemon clean uninstallAll
```